# Calculating average curvature of a polygonal chain with non-uniform segment length

Tags: geometry, curve

I'm using a polygonal chain to approximate a curve. I want to approximate the average of a function of curvature of all points that lie on the curve. One function of curvature that I need is, for example, the square of curvature.

I can get near that by choosing some points on the chain, calculating the curvature in those points, applying the function on it (for example squaring it), and then averaging the calculated values.

I need both accuracy and speed. I appreciate both — fast, but approximate; as well as accurate, but slow solutions. I'm working in Java, but the answer doesn't need to be written in Java — it doesn't even need to contain any code at all.

## Polygonal chain with uniform segment length

If the polygonal chain's segments all have equal length, I can just calculate the curvature in the vertices and then average that. I see two ways to get the curvature in a vertex.

One way is to get the circle that goes through the selected vertex, the vertex before it, and the one after it. The curvature is then 1/radius of the circle.

[image]

The other way is to calculate the external angle (in radians) of the two segments connected at the selected vertex and then divide its absolute value by the length of a segment. In the following image, φ marks the external angle:

[image]

I am not sure if this method is correct, as I haven't mathematically derived it, but I've noticed through experimentation that it gives similar results to the above method.

## Polygonal chain with non-uniform segment length

Unfortunately, though, there's no guarantee that the segments have uniform length.

If I try using the first of the above methods, vertices connected to longer segments give lower curvatures, even if they are visibly sharper. I tried substituting previous and next vertices with a point x units before the selected vertex and a point x units after it. I don't know what to set the x constant to, to get accurate results. All the values I've tried seemed to give inaccurate results.

If I try using the second method, I don't know what length to divide the angle by. If I don't divide by anything at all, I actually get pretty good results for comparing two curves and determining which one is curvier, but I need to be able to determine the actual curvature in a point.

With both of these methods there's also the problem that parts with shorter segments (where points are denser) will affect the average more.

Another possible solution would be to ignore the vertices and instead use an array of points on the chain that *are* evenly spaced, treat them as a new polygonal chain (connect the points with straight lines), and then calculate curvatures on this new chain instead, using one of the methods I mentioned under the header titled "Polygonal chain with uniform segment length".

Finding such an array of points is not trivial, though, because I have to choose a segment length, and only after producing the points, I can see if the length of the resulting chain is divisible by the chosen segment length.

Comment: I wonder whether your idea works even with uniform segment length. If you change the length of both segments but keep everything else equal, the situation looks the same locally at the 'selected vertex'. But your calculated radius and curvature would be different.

Comment: That's a good thought, but I think that if you change the length of both segments, the segments are now representing a different curve (a less curvy one, if the segment length is increased), so the calculated curvature should be different.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't short on space, the last solution you mentioned would be the best, because the "sphere" approximation, as you've perhaps realized, would give awful results in more extreme cases, especially if the curvature is large or changes sign quickly.

There are many ways to do interpolations, the simplest being quadratic and cubic splines. However if you have more pre-processing time, *Lagrange polynomials* produce very good results: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial.

---

Side note on your angle division method, consider this diagram:

[image]

(From simple geometry the inside angle there is *also* theta)

[image]

For `a << l`. So the curvature:

[image]

So your approximation is in fact *correct* for small curvatures.

Comment: Thanks for answering. :) But I need some clarification. By "the last solution", do you mean finding a new array of points that *is* equally spaced? That is not a full solution. If I do that, I will have only reduced the problem to calculating average curvature of a polygonal chain with *uniform* segment length. I'll still have to use either the 1/circle_radius or the angle/length method.

So, you're suggesting that I find a new, similar chain, one that does have segments of uniform length and then use the angle/length method, since sphere approximation can give bad results. Is that correct?

Comment: @user2623008 I'm suggesting that you compute a new equally spaced array with a good (but possibly expensive, like the lagrange thing) method, _if and only if_ you don't mind the precomputation time

Comment: I have tried doing that with Catmull-Rom splines, but I've had some problems. If I take two points that are *d* units apart on the Catmull-Rom spline, they may be closer to each other when connected with a straight line, which means that the resulting polygonal chain may not be uniform in segment length. If I try to find points on the spline that are actually equally spaced (with straight lines), it gets more expensive to compute and the last point might be different than the original's last point. But this is almost ripe for a new question. Again, thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use a local parabola approximation to estimate the curvature. Basically, to estimate the curvature at point P(i), you take P(i-1), P(i) and P(i+1) and construct a parabola from these 3 points. Then, you compute the curvature at P(i) from the parabola. Remember to use chord-length (or centripetal) parametrization when constructing the parabola.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, that is indeed a valid way for a polygonal chain with uniform segment length. Do you think it'd be better than doing it with a circle? Curvature is often defined as the inverse of radius, so a circle is the first thing that came to my mind. Also, I think I'd need four points, as there are infinitely many parabolas going through three points.

Comment: You only need 3 points to create a parabola as a parabola is basically a degree 2 polynomial. From my experience, local approximation with a parabola will achieve better result than using a circular arc. But there are always exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, you are right, you do only need three points. I don't know what I was thinking.